# how to implement search that can access complete database in Django

Tags: django

My views.py

```
class SearchView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'search.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        q = request.GET.get('q', '')
        self.results = Item.objects.filter(title__icontains=q)
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return super().get_context_data(results=self.results, **kwargs)
```

My urls.py

```
url(r'^search/$', SearchView.as_view(), name='search')
```

My search.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% load static %} {% block content %}

<body>
    <h1>Search Result</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for item in q %}
        <li>
            {{ q.title }}, {{ q.price }}
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

</body>
{% endblock%}}
```

My nav.html

```
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'core:search' %}">
```

This is the code that i used but due to some missing or error in this above code i can't get any data if i make any search in my website, Can some one please tell me what is the mistake i have done.
Thank you.

My Models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_no = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: I think you should use {{ item.title }}, {{ item.price }} in the template instead of {{ q.title }}, {{ q.price }}

Comment: I already tried it but it is not working

Comment: would you provide models.py

Comment: My Models.py code

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_no = models.CharField(max_length=100)

Comment: why are you using products in this line:  {% for item in products %}, where is it coming from?

Comment: before i used product=request.GET.get('q', '') and later changed to  q = request.GET.get('q', '') and forget to change in my html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['results'] = self.results
        return context
```

in html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% load static %} 

{% block content %}

<body>
    <h1>Search Result</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for item in results %}
        <li>
            {{ item.title }}, {{ item.price }}
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

</body>
{% endblock%}}
```

Comment: should i change any thing in my urls.py or not.

Comment: write this:
url('search/', SearchView.as_view(), name='search')

You have to get your "q" in get() function from somewhere, so that the url must be something like 'search/?q=abc'.

Comment: I tried to execute the changed code but it is showing error at context in views.py

Comment: Name Error: name 'context' is not defined

Comment: forgot a line: context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs), added in answer

Comment: Thank you for the answer, It is showing the search results, How to add link to redirect to the item showed on search result page.

Comment: link in the template to the item is something like this:  <a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}">{{ item.title }}</a> , but before use you have to write method get_absolute_url() in model for item, look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url